# SassError: Undefined variable: $form-select-border-radius-sm

Tags: symfony, sass, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap in a Symfony 6 project with scss.
When trying to load a page it shows the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable.
   ╷
88 │ $s2bs5-border-radius-sm:         $form-select-border-radius-sm !default;

   │                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  node_modules/select2-bootstrap-5-theme/src/_variables.scss 88:34  @import
  node_modules/select2-bootstrap-5-theme/src/_include-all.scss 1:9  @import
  assets/styles/app.scss 4:9                                        root stylesheet
    at processResult (/Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:701:19)
    at runLoaders (/Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:807:5)
    at /Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at /Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (/Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at render (/Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:54:7)
    at Function.call$2 (/Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:93417:16)
    at _render_closure1.call$2 (/Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:81775:12)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:27547:18)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/Users/me/git/pub-review/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26096:19)
```

I have the latest version of Bootstrap installed and cannot find where this error is coming from.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the issue. I didn't notice that my
npm run dev
failed. I had to install:

```
yarn add @babel/preset-env --dev
yarn add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties --dev
```